# Anchors in Yaml

Tags: parsing, yaml

I'm currently learning Yaml and have a problem with this code:

http://hastebin.com/focokeqawo.sm

```
---
classes:
  audio:
    - &Music components.audio.Music
    - &Sound components.audio.Sound
  graphic:
    - &Animation components.graphic.Animation
    - &Image components.graphic.Image
    - &Text components.graphic.Text
  misc:
    - &Camera components.misc.Camera
    - &Debug components.misc.Debug
  collider:
    - &Circle components.physics.Circle
    - &Hitbox components.physics.Hitbox
    - &Polygon components.physics.Polygon
  common:
    - &Physics components.Physics
    - &Transform components.Transform

&Wabbit Wabbit:
  name: Wabbit
  components:
    -
      type: *Transform
      x: 150
      y: 120
    -
      type: *Image
      file: Wabbit
    -
      type: *Physics
    -
      type: *Debug

&Coin Coin:
  name: Coin
  components:
    -
      type: *Transform
      x: 370
      y: 180
      scaleX: 5
      scaleY: 5
    -
      type: *Physics
    -
      type: *Debug

&Ground Ground:
  name: Ground
  components:
    -
      type: *Transform
      x: 320
      y: 475


&TestScene TestScene:
  type: Scene
  gameObjects: [*Wabbit, *Coin, *Ground]
  extensions: [Nape]

Engine:
  name: Example
  scene: *TestScene
  paused: false
  debug: true

Screen:
  color: [146, 150, 152] #grey
  scaleX: 1
  scaleY: 1
  zoom: 1
```

The "gameObjects" Array at the bottom is parsed as a String Array but i expected it to contain the actual data of the anchors(&). I'm also using anchors at the top and they work fine.

Question: Do yaml anchors also work for complex data?

Comment: They should work. Which YAML parser do you use?

Comment: @delnan a pretty unknown one https://github.com/mikestead/hx-yaml

Comment: Then I am inclined to say the problem is either with your use of that parser's API (perhaps you need a special invocation to resolve anchors?) or with the parser's implementation of anchors. I couldn't tell which one at a glance though.

Comment: @delnan Thanks i guess it's a bug in the parser. Can you post a answer so i can close the question?

Comment: I'm not at all sure whether it's a bug in the parser, especially since the example on the readme features an anchor with complex data.